# Rails 3 link_to and JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use Rails to show links (featuring `:remote => true`) on a page, "currentPage" using `jQuery.append()`.

What I want to do:
I am using Juggernaut (a push server) to push data from "currentPage" to update a counter of another page, using the following code (which doesn't work). Am I on the right track? If there is an easier/better-form way to do this, please let me know.

```
var push_question_link = "<%= escape_javascript(link_to('Link', 'results')) %><br />";
$('#myDiv').append(push_question_link)
```

I want the 'Link' string to be a JavaScript variable, but once I use `escape_javascript` I can't call the variable.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the href property of that link with your variable after you have done a .append(push_question_link)

Even though the rails link_to statement will generate the link with a static url, manually overriding it next might do the trick.  Good luck!